# Mutiple iterators in for loop Java not working properly

Tags: javascript, java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to pass a Javascript code to Java, but I've got a problem with the for loop, I have a for with 2 iterators in my Javascript code, and it is working as intended, but on Java it is not, am I missing something?

I let you just the for loop structure, as I am pretty sure the remaining logic is working good.

It is a large chunk of code, but **the problem on Java is that after the loop finishes it does not continue with the remaining code, as you can see the System.out.println("Not running from here, after the for loop is completed"); it just does not appear on console, It just stops after the loop is done.** Am I mising something?

This is my code in Javascript:

```
function addTraceData(s1, s2, trace) {
var rows = trace.length - 1;
var cols = trace[0].length - 1;

var s1aligned = [];
var s2aligned = [];

var best, bestX, bestY, curX, curY;
var strings = ['', ''];
for (curX = 1, curY = 1; curX <= cols && curY <= rows;) {
    console.log(curX, curY)
    best = -1;
    bestX = curX;
    bestY = curY;
    for (var y = curY; y <= rows; y++) {
        if (trace[y][0] == trace[0][curX] && trace[y][curX] > best) {
            best = trace[y][curX];
            bestX = curX;
            bestY = y;
        }
    }
    for (var x = curX; x <= cols; x++) {
        if (trace[curY][0] == trace[0][x] && trace[curY][x] > best) {
            best = trace[curY][x];
            bestX = x;
            bestY = curY;
        }
    }
    if (best >= 0) {
        // trace[bestY][bestX] = '<span class="bg-danger"><b>&nbsp;' + trace[bestY][bestX] + '&nbsp;</b></span>';
        var diffX = bestX - curX;
        var diffY = bestY - curY;
        strings[0] += repeat('-', diffY);
        strings[1] += repeat('-', diffX);
        for (var i = 0; i < diffX && curX + i <= cols; i++) {
            strings[0] += trace[0][curX + i];
            // strings[1] += trace[curX + i][0];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < diffY && curY + i <= rows; i++) {
            strings[1] += trace[curY + i][0];
            // strings[0] += trace[0][curY + i];
        }
        strings[0] += trace[0][bestX];
        strings[1] += trace[bestY][0];
    } else {
        strings[0] += '-';
        strings[1] += '-';
    }
    curX = bestX + 1;
    curY = bestY + 1;
}

for (var i = curX; i <= cols; i++) {
    strings[0] += trace[0][i];
    strings[1] += '-';
}
for (var i = curY; i <= rows; i++) {
    strings[1] += trace[i][0];
    strings[0] += '-';
}
return strings;
```

}

This is my code in Java:

```
public static void generarAlineamientoMejorado(String s1, String s2, String[][] trace) {
    int rows = trace.length - 1;
    int cols = trace[0].length - 1;

    int best, bestX, bestY;
    var curX = 1;
    var curY = 1;
    String firstString = "";
    String secondString = "";

    for (curX = 1, curY = 1; curX <= cols && curY <= rows;) {
        System.out.println(curX + " " + curY);
        best = -1;
        bestX = curX;
        bestY = curY;
        for (int y = curY; y <= rows; y++) {
            if (trace[y][0].equals(trace[0][curX]) && Integer.parseInt(trace[y][curX]) > best) {
                best = Integer.parseInt(trace[y][curX]);
                bestX = curX;
                bestY = y;
            }
        }
        for (int x = curX; x <= cols; x++) {
            if (trace[curY][0].equals(trace[0][x]) && Integer.parseInt(trace[curY][x]) > best) {
                best = Integer.parseInt(trace[curY][x]);
                bestX = x;
                bestY = curY;
            }
        }

        if (best >= 0) {
            // trace[bestY][bestX] = '<span class="bg-danger"><b>&nbsp;' +
            // trace[bestY][bestX] + '&nbsp;</b></span>';
            int diffX = bestX - curX;
            int diffY = bestY - curY;
            firstString += repeat("-", diffY);
            secondString += repeat("-", diffX);
            for (int i = 0; i < diffX && curX + i <= cols; i++) {
                firstString += trace[0][curX + i];
                // secondString += trace[curX + i][0];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < diffY && curY + i <= rows; i++) {
                secondString += trace[curY + i][0];
                // firstString += trace[0][curY + i];
            }
            firstString += trace[0][bestX];
            secondString += trace[bestY][0];
        } else {
            firstString += "-";
            secondString += "-";
        }
        curX = bestX + 1;
        curY = bestY + 1;
    }

   System.out.println("Not running from here, after the for loop is completed");
    
    for (var i = curX; i <= cols; i++) {
        firstString += trace[0][i];
        secondString += '-';
    }
    for (var i = curY; i <= rows; i++) {
        secondString += trace[i][0];
        firstString += '-';
    }
}
```

I have been searching through the internet and I found a post with the similar structure, but it is not working as intended, what am I missing?

Thank you in advance, sorry if my english is not that good.

Comment: Does "not working properly" mean there's a compile error?  Or is it just doing the wrong thing?  Did you try it without the extra `curY++, curX++` - the fact that you didn't have them in the JavaScript suggests that those numbers are actually changing in the body of the loop, so you probably don't want to increment them in the loop header as well.

Comment: Unless curX and curY are created elsewhere, you will need to specify their type like so `for (int curX = 1, curY = 1;`

Comment: You need to add some debugging to find out why the remainder of the code does not appear to be running. Do you know for certain that the `for` loops are never entered? If so then the condition is never mot, for example, is `curX` already greater than `cols` on this line `for (var i = curX; i <= cols; i++)`? Use println to print out the value of them, or step through it with a debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically i am not seeing any issue with your code,

but are you sure you need to increment curX and curY in java code, you haven't incremented it in js code.

```
for (curX = 1, curY = 1; curX <= cols && curY <= rows; ) {}
```

also have you declared variable in java before that?

```
for (int curX = 1, curY = 1; curX <= cols && curY <= rows; ) {}
```

question is unclear, but hope this should work

---

according to comment, i can see that you need the opposite, but it should work just fine if you add ++ in js

```
> for (curX = 1, curY = 1; curX <= cols && curY <= rows;curX++,curY++){console.log("hello")}
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
undefined
```

i ran this in nodejs without any issue

Comment: I noticed that if I add the increment to my Javascript code it stops working, but if I remove the increment to my Java code it completes the for loop with no problem, but the remaining code outside the for loop stops working, like it stops after the for loop when there is no increment, any ideas why?

Comment: Note that `for (int curX = 1,int curY = 1;...` is not valid syntax, instead use `for (int curX = 1, curY = 1;...`

Comment: Thanks, i haven't tested it i just directly typed in answer... i will edit accordingly

Comment: @MarioAlmaguer , can you specify what you actually want?? 
 adding increment operation of both variable at the end should work in js. please print out values and check, 
this code seems to be a part of some sort of graph, so that  might be going to -ve part.

Comment: I just edited the post, the problem is that on Java it stops running the method after the for loop is done.